# 2 gang 2 way switch button on and off are reverse

Tags: switch

I have a 2 gang 2 way switch for 2 lights (corridor light and bathroom light).

COM1, LA1 and LA2 is for switch 1 (Bulb 1).

COM2, LB1 and LB2 is for switch 2 (Bulb 2).

Remark: Those yellow cable are yellow, so we don't know which is live wire.

[image]

When the switches are on. The bulb 2 is on but the bulb 1 is off.
[image]

When the switches are off. The bulb 2 is off but the bulb 1 is on.
[image]

The button switch 1 (bulb 1) is reverse. How to make it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2-way switches (US: 3-way) but you're only using them as 1-way.   Which is fine.

But for some reason you wired the always-live wires to to Com1 on one side but LB1 on the other.  Weird.  Limits your choice somewhat.

Move LA2 to LA1.   Now, the switches will act together.

If that's upside down of what you want, then rotate the entire switch assembly 180 degrees.